# Assigning and Resigning first responder in text field

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3

I was implementing an OTP functionality as shown in this one [Auto Resign and assign first responder in text field in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38610286/auto-resign-and-assign-first-responder-in-text-field-in-swift) but getting an error in these following lines as they have been deprecated for Swift 3

```
    let start = text!.startIndex.advancedBy(range.location)
    let end = start.advancedBy(range.length)
```

What's the workaround for this?

Comment: add error in question .

Comment: use [textField resignFirstResponder]  & [textField becomeFirstResponder] are the methods but what are you getting error in using these?

Comment: 'advancedBy' is unavailable: To advance an index by n steps call 'index(_:offsetBy:)' on the CharacterView instance that produced the index.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement otp functionality. Below is the code you can use.
Each text field is having tag, and as according to tag value you can easily respond to next text field.

```
extension YOUR_VC:UITextFieldDelegate{

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
 // to make text field empty    
 textField.text = ""
}


func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    if(string.length == 1){
        textField.text = string
        textField.resignFirstResponder();

    }
    return false
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    // for making next text field first responder after a character is entered in previous textfield
    switch textField.tag {
    case 1:
        otpTextTwo.becomeFirstResponder()
    case 2:
        otpTextThree.becomeFirstResponder()
    case 3:
        otpTextFour.becomeFirstResponder()
    case 4:
        otpTextFive.becomeFirstResponder()
    case 5:
        otpTextSix.becomeFirstResponder()
    case 6:

       // self.doneFecthingOtp()
    default:
        //print("NOt case")
    }
} }
```

hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

You should write like this in swift3:

```
let start = text?.index((text?.startIndex)!, offsetBy: range.location)
let end = text?.index(start!, offsetBy: range.length)
let indexRange = text?[start! ..< end!]
```